# Adding Wagtail to an existing Django app

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm quite new to Django and Wagtail, and I'm having some difficulty with what I think is a very basic use.

How do I allow Wagtail to edit an existing view's template, while serving that template using Django's serving mechanism?

Assume I have an app (HomePage) created to serve the site's main index (/). I have the HomePage's views set up to render template and certain elements dynamically. Now I want that template to be editable via Wagtail's CMS interface. Something as simple as an image on the frontpage, or a headline.

The closest I've gotten so far has been to follow the Wagtail beginner's tutorial to override the base HomePage class in my app's models.py. That only made my pages available via the /pages/ URL.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Since your site's home page is not a Page object in the Wagtail sense, I'd suggest looking at Wagtail's facilities for managing non-page content - [snippets](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/topics/snippets.html) and [ModelAdmin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html) would be possible candidates, but I reckon the [site settings](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/reference/contrib/settings.html) module would be the best fit.

A Setting model gives you a set of fields which can be configured for display in the Wagtail admin using a 'panels' definition, just like you'd get for a page model - with the important property that only one settings record exists per site. You can retrieve this record within your homepage view or template [as shown in the docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/reference/contrib/settings.html#using-the-settings), and output it on your template as desired.

Answer (score 1):

One way do that, is to let Wagtail serve your homepage. You will need to change your project's url configuration accordingly, to make wagtail's urls serve the root of your site.

Then, you can pack your dynamic content into a custom template_tag and include in your homepage html template.